# upgrade to the manifest V3, chome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry is not a function

Tags: google-chrome-extension

when a use `chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry`, it fire a bug:

Error img1

[image: 1]

and when a debugger `chrome.runtime` Object, i couldn't find `getPackageDirectoryEntry` property:

Error img2

[image: 2]

this problem does not appear when I use manifest V2,
and I've searched a lot and couldn't find a solution to this problem

Comment: It's not supported in service worker. There's no replacement. Why do you need it?

Comment: Please post the code as text not an image.

Comment: @wOxxOm Because I wrote it in the vue framework and then turned it into js, ​​I want to listen to vue changes to change the extension in real time, so as to debug the code

Comment: If you use a build tool, you can generate the list of files at build time, then use `fetch` on each one to check for change.